# Vue + Express(NestJS) Impossible task, You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where

Tags: express, vue.js, vuejs2, nestjs, server-side-rendering

It's making it impossible for me to add Vue as a view system to a framework called Nest with Express.

I didn't think that adapting Vue was so complicated. That's why I'm here so that you can guide me on the right path and I won't use Vue directly.

Fist the error:

```
    [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
(found in <Root>)
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Render, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createRenderer } from 'vue-server-renderer';
import { createApp } from './app';
import HelloComponent from './components/Hello';
const context = {data: {}, view: '', componets: {} };

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  getHello(@Response() res): any {
    context.data = { message: 'Esto es un nuevo mensaje 2' };
    context.componets = { 'hello' : HelloComponent };
    const app = createApp(context);
    const renderer = createRenderer();
    renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
      res.end(html);
    });
  }
}
```

import { createApp } from './app';

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export function createApp(context: any) {
  return new Vue({
    data: context.data,
    template: fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf-8'),
    components: context.components,
  }).$mount('#app');
}
```

I try is to have a base template and then add the components for each controller or route with NestJS.

I don't know if this is possible and if I'm forced to use Webpack, since I'm not currently using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue launched an entire site to walk you through getting your server side rendering up and running. It is NOT the same process that is outlined at https://vuejs.org.

Complete information can be found at: https://ssr.vuejs.org/ and is referenced in the main guide about halfway down the sidebar navigation under the heading serverside rendering https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

Here is the gist of it to get you started:

```
npm install express --save

npm install vue vue-server-renderer --save
```

Integrating with your server example

```
const Vue = require('vue')
const server = require('express')()
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const app = new Vue({
    data: {
      url: req.url
    },
    template: `<div>The visited URL is: {{ url }}</div>`
  })

  renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).end('Internal Server Error')
      return
    }
    res.end(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head><title>Hello</title></head>
        <body>${html}</body>
      </html>
    `)
  })
})

server.listen(8080)
```

Rendering a Vue Instance

```
// Step 1: Create a Vue instance
const Vue = require('vue')
const app = new Vue({
  template: `<div>Hello World</div>`
})

// Step 2: Create a renderer
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()

// Step 3: Render the Vue instance to HTML
renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(html)
  // => <div data-server-rendered="true">Hello World</div>
})

// in 2.5.0+, returns a Promise if no callback is passed:
renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
  console.log(html)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already followed that, the problem I'm having is that I can not use any template base, and then in controller only inject the component. That's not in the documentation and I can't find anything on google.

Comment: I can't believe I finally made it. https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#using-a-page-template  Thanks thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully it's not that complicated of an issue.

You are attempting to use the `runtime` build on `.ts` files, which you cannot. This is because only `*.vue` because they are pre-compiled.

To get around this, simply create an alias to vue in webpack:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

Which will give you access to the template-compiler allowing you to use `Vue` inside of non pre-compiled templates (read: any file not ending in .vue)

Comment: I think it might be better to add VUE directly into html, but I can have the same problems being an Express framework.